# I am trying to perform a filter, count, and sort on a Django 1.6 dataset

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am making a little word matching game with django where I start the user with a word (model: refword) and they type in what they think the next word (model: word) should be.

The word they type in then becomes the next refword awaiting for a word.

Ex:

1. Home page displays "When I say Green, you say **_**."
2. User types and submits "Tree"
3. Then the next page displays "When I say Tree, you say **__**."

**Problem:**
After the user submits "Tree" on the second step and goes to step 3, I would like to show what *other users typed in and the counts of those word pairs*.

See Desired Result section of my question below. I have been having a hard time getting the queries in my view to get me close to what I want.

So continuing with this example, let's say the user gets "When I say Green, you say **_**" and types in "Tree."

This writes refword: Green and word: Tree to the database.

**Sample Database Data**

```
refword word
------- -------
green   grass
green   grass
blue    sky
blue    diamond
green   clover
green   tree
green   grass
blue    sky
red     sky
green   party
red     head
green   day
green   tree <--- what the user just typed in
```

**Desired Display Result**

Here's what has been said so far:

```
refword word    qty
------- ------- ---
green   grass   3
green   tree    2
green   clover  1
green   day     1
green   party   1
```

**Here's my understanding of what would need to happen to create this.**

Filtering: Show distinct results for the refword "green"

Calculations: Calculate and display the sum of times each result appears.

Sorting: 
Sort by quantity descending so highest qty is at the top.
Sub-sort alphabetically ascending (A to Z) (ex: green clover, green day, and green party all have 1 one result, so sort the alpha ascending sort puts clover at the top.)

Here are some code snips of

**models.py**

```
class Word(models.Model):
word = models.CharField(max_length=200)
refword = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**form.py**

```
class WordForm(forms.Form):
word = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
```

**views.py**

I'm setting up my view like this

```
def submitword(request):
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted...
    form = WordForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
        word = form.cleaned_data['word']        
        referring_word = request.session["referring_word"] #setup the session
        word_form_data = Word(word=word, refword=referring_word)
```

**Template file**

```
<p>When I said {{ ref_word }} you said {% form.word.value %}</p>
<p>Here's what has been said so far:</p>
```

Comment: I feel you should edit your Word model to also have a count field then you could increase it if both word and refword match else create a new row. Then you could use the query like word.objects.all().orderby('-count','refword',word'). The summing part is unnecessary

Comment: Good advice. I'm trying that now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a online query that you can use to get required info.
Suboptimal way would be to use `distinct('word')` and then get count for each work. But it will only work with pgsql.

```
qs = Word.objects.filter(refword=referringword).distinct('word')
cnt_list = dict()
for w in qs:
    cnt_list.update({w.word: Word.objects.filter(refword=w.refword, word=w.word).count()})
```

---

Other way without using `distinct()` and 2nd set of queries is...

Use `values()` to get dict of required objects and use `regroup` template filter tag to show the words and their count. But in this case sorting cannot be done on word count.

```
#views
word_list = Word.objects.filter(refword=referringword).values('refword', 'word')
#pass this to template

#template
{% regroup word_list|dictsort:"word" by word as word_count %}
<ul>
    {%for wl in word_count %}
       <li> {{wl.grouper}} : {{wl.list|length}} </li>
    {%endfor%}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm using SQLite3 right now but when I port to pgsql I'll investigate this further. There's a lot for me to dig into here. You clarified for me that I was barking up the wrong tree. I'm also trying @mascot6699's suggestion of adding a count field in my database.